# Mongodb doctrine query not loading referenced objects

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have these classes:

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
*/
class Expansion
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $name;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Expansion")
     */
    protected $expansion;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $number; 

}

 /**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */
class Price
{

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Product")
     */
    protected $product;
}
```

If I got any Expansion's id, I can load every price of products referred to him:

```
$db_expansion = $dm->getRepository('SampleCollectionBundle:Expansion')->findOneById($expansionId);

$db_product = $dm->createQueryBuilder('SampleCollectionBundle:Product')->select('id')->field('expansion')->references($db_expansion)->getQuery()->toArray();

$product_ids = array_keys($db_product);

$db_prices = $dm->createQueryBuilder('SampleCollectionBundle:Price')->field('product.id')->in($product_ids)->getQuery();
```

But this query only returns simple Price objects, How can I get (on Twig, by the way) product's numbers? I tried `{{ price.product.number }}` but obviously doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "obviosly doesn't work"? Does `price.product.number` return null, throw an Exception or what?

Comment: Solved, I forgot to add '->execute()' at the end of $db_prices queryBuilder